# check the order & validate arguments to shell script

Tags: validation, shell, arguments, command-line-arguments, optional-arguments

I know similar questions may be asked on this ,but I am a total newbie to shell scripting & not finding help (may be I am not able to understand the technicalities). I have a simple question:

I have a simple script (testscript.sh) which needs 3 arguments & I am passing these using three parameters & running it like: (1st argument is a simple string, 2nd is the path to a filename & 3rd is a folder name)

```
./testscript.sh --para1 "somestring" --para2 "/home/android/test/abc.xml" --para3 "/home/android/outputfolder"
```

Now I want to check whether the user has given provided all the reqd input values with proper parameters. I mean para3 must contain folder name, para2 must be a filename & para1 must be the string OR they come in the same sequence.

Also I would like to validate one more thing: currently I am expecting the user will enter the filename "/home/android/test/abc.xml" enclosed in double qoutes, but if the user doesnt enclose it in double quotes & the folder/filename has a space in it, it would create issues, as I am not able to get the complete file/folder name including the spaces, it is breaking.

Plz help. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't exactly match with my requirements, but go it working by this way:  Modified the way the script runs to :

```
./testscript.sh -p "somestring" -i "/home/android/test/abc.xml" -o "/home/android/outputfolder"
```

& added checks in the script as:

```
while getopts ":p:i:o:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    p)
      if [ "$OPTARG" = "abc" ] || [ "$OPTARG" = "xyz" ]; then
        somestring=$OPTARG
      else
        echo "Invalid parameter" >&2
        usage
      fi
      ;;
    i)
      if [ -e $OPTARG ] && [ -f $OPTARG ]; then 
    input=$OPTARG
       else
        echo "Input file doest'nt exist " >&2
        usage
      fi
      ;;
    o)
      if [ -e $OPTARG ]; then
    ouput=$OPTARG
      else
        echo "Output folder doest'nt exist " >&2
        usage
      fi
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

But still anyone finds an exact solution to my question (with "--para1"), answers are welcome !

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```sh
#!/bin/sh

usage ()
{
  echo "usage: $0 STRING FILE DIRECTORY"
  exit
}

[ -n "$1" ] || usage
[ -e "$2" ] || usage
[ -d "$3" ] || usage
```

[**ref**](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html)

Comment: Thanks for this svnpenn, by this I can check whether $2, $4 & $6 are string, file & folder but is there a way that I can check that value for "--para1" is string, "--para2" is file && "--para1" is folder ?